# I need to create output from json that is pretty

Tags: python, json, dictionary, output

I am getting data from active directory, exporting it to JSON. That's great. I can then return the output via *json.loads()*.

```
if output != '':
            return json.loads(output)
```

Then I get ugly json output unusable to the end user. Can I convert this to a Python dictionary or is there another module that might display the data in a user acceptable view?

I tried to convert the JSON with Python *json.decoder*

I get the following error when attempting to json.decode:

> TypeError:  is
>   not JSON serializable

I've tried the suggestions but it's not working. To date the following code is the only interation that works, no formatting available:

```
for server in ADDomainList:
    counter += 1
    psCommand = 'get-ADUser ' + cdsid + ' -Server ' + server + ' -Properties * | 
                 SELECT custom1,custom2,custom3,custom4 | ConvertTo-Json'

    proc = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe ', psCommand] 
           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    output = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

    if output != '':
       return json.loads(output)
    if counter > 5:
           return 'AD Server Cannot Be Located'
```

I get:

"custom1": "dummy1", 
  "custom10": "dummy10", 
 
  "custom2": "dummy2", 
  "custom3": "dummy3",

I would like to return:

Field Name1: Data1 
Field Name10: Data10

no quotes, no delimiters, just the facts...

Comment: If your json is a `dict` object (which is what `loads` does) use `print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4))`

Comment: or you can use pretty print: `https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pprint.html`

Comment: `import pprint
pprint.pprint(json)`

Comment: I've tried the suggestions but it's not working. To date the following code is the only interation that works and this has no formatting available as is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pprint.html) module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter. Here is an example of how you could use it to pretty print a JSON object.

```
import json
import pprint
from urllib.request import urlopen
with urlopen('http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser/json') as url:
    http_info = url.info()
    raw_data = url.read().decode(http_info.get_content_charset())
project_info = json.loads(raw_data)
result = {'headers': http_info.items(), 'body': project_info}
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
{'body': {'info': {'_pypi_hidden': False,
                   '_pypi_ordering': 12,
                   'classifiers': ['Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
                                   'Intended Audience :: Developers',
                                   'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
                                   'Natural Language :: English',
                                   'Operating System :: OS Independent',
                                   'Programming Language :: Python',
                                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
                                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
                                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
                                   'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries',
                                   'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'],
                   'download_url': 'UNKNOWN',
                   'home_page': 'http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/configparser.html',
                   'keywords': 'configparser ini parsing conf cfg configuration file',
                   'license': 'MIT',
                   'name': 'configparser',
                   'package_url': 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser',
                   'platform': 'any',
                   'release_url': 'http://pypi.python.org/pypi/configparser/3.2.0r3',
                   'requires_python': None,
                   'stable_version': None,
                   'summary': 'This library brings the updated configparser from Python 3.2+ to Python 2.6-2.7.',
                   'version': '3.2.0r3'},
        'urls': [{'comment_text': '',
                  'downloads': 47,
                  'filename': 'configparser-3.2.0r3.tar.gz',
                  'has_sig': False,
                  'md5_digest': '8500fd87c61ac0de328fc996fce69b96',
                  'packagetype': 'sdist',
                  'python_version': 'source',
                  'size': 32281,
                  'upload_time': '2011-05-10T16:28:50',
                  'url': 'http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/configparser/configparser-3.2.0r3.tar.gz'}]},
'headers': [('Date', 'Sat, 14 May 2011 12:48:52 GMT'),
            ('Server', 'Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)'),
            ('Content-Disposition', 'inline'),
            ('Connection', 'close'),
            ('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked'),
            ('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset="UTF-8"')]}
```

Comment: Thank you, I believe pprint is the best option. Other than that, I'll send it to the Web Front end make it user friendly there.

Answer (score 0):

The json module already implements some basic pretty printing with the indent parameter:

```
import json

json_ = '["foo", {"bar":["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]}]'
parsed = json.loads(json_)
print (json.dumps(parsed, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

output:

```
[
  "foo",
  {
    "bar": [
      "val1",
      "val2",
      "val3",
      "val4"
    ]
  }
]
```

> **indent:** the number of spaces to indent by (Without the indent, you just get a single line)